# Adding a table in an iBook popover

Tags: popover, ibooks, ibook-author

I'm trying to add a table (i.e. a small grid) into a popover in an iBook I am trying to author.

Problem is: I have no idea how to do it. All I seem to be able to add are images and text boxes. The table is grayed out.

I tried creating a table in Numbers and cutting and pasting it in - but that did not work.

Any ideas?

Can I drop down to HTML to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do it is

1. Create a page at the end of the book
2. Create the table
3. Take a screen grab of the table
4. Paste the image into the popover

This does have the (small) advantage of having a single place with all the tables.